# Software tools for taking screenshots

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, test-management, test-design, gui

I am currently using `jing` software tool to take screenshot for bugs.

Could anyone let me know Is there any other tools in the market to take screenshot very effectively and quickly?

Comment: there are lot of browser **Plug Ins** available for all browsers. Search and Select the necessary plug in

Comment: this question is much better asked in http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ - all answers here are opinion-based

Comment: Sorry, but this sort of question is off topic here. There are subjective questions allowed, but this doesn't really meet the criteria. I agree with peter that this question would be better at software recs, but I didn't migrate it there because it needs much more detailed requirements before they'd allow it.

Answer (score 4):

> There are number of tools available in the market for Screen capture. You can download from following links.

1. Greenshot:
2. PicPick: http://ngwin.com/picpick/update?AVGAFFILIATE=11859
3. Gadwin PrintScreen: http://www.gadwin.com/download/
4. Jing : https://www.techsmith.com/jing.html
5. SnagIt: https://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html

Answer (score 1):

I have here 2 free testing tools: **Nimbus** and **HotShots**.

I see the Nimbus (https://nimbus.everhelper.me/screenshot.php) as a rising star of screenshot tools for testers. It enables some after-capture functionalities such as highlighting, frames, text comments etc.

**Nimbus:**

[image: Nimbus screenshot]

It is available as Chrome and Firefox addons, works on Android and runs on Windows.

Unfortunatelly it is not distributed in Linux. In browsers I'm using Nimbus, as Nimbus is able to take whole content of the browser scrolling from the top down but for the Linux desktop I'm running HotShots (http://thehive.xbee.net/index.php?module=pages&func=display&pageid=31), which offers similar functionality for desktop systems.

**HotShots**:

[image: Hotshots screenshot]

Comment: I tried Nimbus its good but not able to take screen cast from Nimbus tool

Comment: nothing about screencast in your question... so nothing is in the answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [PrtScr](http://www.fiastarta.com/PrtScr/)

It is quick, and simple...

Lets you take a full screen screenshot, or draw the area you want...

It also lets you draw with a red line "pen"

And you can save the image where you want, or save it on desktop, or simply copy the image to clipboard...

[image]

Try it...

Answer (score -1):

Try Awesome screenshot. It has plugin for both chrome and firefox

[Click here for Awesome Screenshot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/awesome-screenshot-screen/nlipoenfbbikpbjkfpfillcgkoblgpmj?hl=en)

Comment: try to provide the download link... this may helps the viewer to easily use the tool...

Comment: Hello @Paarthiban NK, have you checked the url that I have mentioned in the answer ??

Comment: oh yea.... i thought that this was an image link. you can notify to user as click to download...